# Write a point on/inside the convex hull of a set of vertices

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis

We work over $\mathbb{R}^N$. We consider a convex hull defined by its $L$ vertices.

- How to write a point $\textbf{on}$ (in) the convex hull in function of all the vertices?
- How to write a point $\textbf{inside}$ the convex hull in function of all the vertices?

Thank you!

Comment: Start with the definition of a convex set.

Comment: I just need to know if it's the same [expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_set#Properties) in both cases.

Comment: Yes, it is. Consider a convex combination of two of your vertices as a linear transformation. You should obtain an inequality, equality being satisfied under certain conditions.